# Setting memory mapped file limit for Windows?

Tags: windows-server-2008, elasticsearch

Hi running Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise. My server has 128GB of RAM.

I'm using Elasticsearch which is configured with ES_HEAP_SIZE=30GB

With Task Manager
Private Working Set: 33GB
Working Set: 97GB

Looking with RAMMap.exe
Process Private Total: 34GB
Process Private Active: 34GB
Mapped File Total: 90GB
Mapped File Active: 64GB

Let's say with all processes running there about 95GB free. Is it possible to tell Windows cache upto 90GB of mapped files and leave 5GB open?

Answer (score 1):

While not an exact match there are APIs available to set file cache sizes or working set sizes, for example [SetSystemFileCacheSize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965240.aspx).

There are utilities around that use these APIs. One such is Sysinternals [CacheSet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897561)

Comment: Yeah I found that one after I posted the question. But it's nothing permanent either. I.e: after reboot I you lose the config and it's not a service either. Hummmm. What would happen if Windows had no more file cache to allocate? Would it swap out older files for newer ones?